# Visualizing custom algorithms on custom data

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, data-visualization, graph-theory, graph-visualization

I have a custom graph algorithm and graph with some additional data in it, and I want to create a tool which creates this graph (Shape and size will be asked via UI) and then modifies it in some way. I tried simple forms and then processing the data with python, outputting and showing a graphviz converted to png. Graphviz makes edgeless graphs in an ugly way - they are in one line.

My goal is to create something more interactive, and user friendlier. My friends recommended me to do this in Unity, although, I have no experience with it. And internet recommends me javascript, but I have been always avoiding web as much as I could... So my Weapons are: Python, Java, C++ (I prefer Python). The tool is not meant to be commercial, it is for educational purposes only. Maybe there is really some simple way I am still missing. I want something similar to this: https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/BTree.html

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If you have a specific problem with some code you have used, please show a minimal, complete, verifiable example. Otherwise this is too broad for the Stack Overflow format.

Comment: Graphviz lets you specify node positions.

Comment: I am rather looking for a recommendation, what is the best way to visualize custom algorithms, step by step.